# How to use Javascript value as Javascript Variable or function

Tags: javascript, dom

is there is any alternate solution for the below javascript code
i need to use JS value as JS variable or function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    var parent_var = '.parentElement'; //dynamically get variable
    while(count == 5){
      parent_var = parent_var+'.parentElement';
      parent = document.getElementById('html_id')+parent_var;
      console.log(parent); 
      count++;
    }
</script>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
parent = document.getElementById('html_id').parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement;
```

---

i need to get parent element dynamically based on some loop count, every loop append .parentElement

it dynamically get before parent in each loop

Thanks in advance ...

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? You say "every loop append" and "each loop" but we don't see any loops.

Comment: now check ... my question . i hope you understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to get the parent element on each loop. Try doing:

```
var currentElement = document.getElementById("html_id");
while (currentElement.tagName.toLowerCase() != "body") {
  currentElement = currentElement.parentElement;
  console.log(currentElement);
}
```

Comment: Thank you :) .. I edited the question and please see expected output.

Comment: Do you want to see that thing or what is returned by that? Also, how far back do you want it to iterate? Eventually it well get to the html page and then to null

Answer (score 0):

Looks you want to let string to be executable code, you could try [eval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function.

```
parent = eval("document.getElementById('html_id')"+parent_var);
```

Comment: Thank you, I got answer here .. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46291542/7052574   and have some security issue. kindly refer below link. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/94021

Comment: As the JS saying goes: eval is evil